# Next js dev works but build fails with ReferenceError: window is not defined on client component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

First time using nextjs, hence only using nextjs without using any features of nextjs.
On next build **Generating static pages** , 6 paths are failing with
**ReferenceError: window is not defined**.

Error

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined

at i (/Users/shubham/Desktop/website/real-estate-website/.next/server/app/site-visits/page.js:1:4471)
at nM (/Users/shubham/Desktop/website/real-estate-website/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
at nN (/Users/shubham/Desktop/website/real-estate-website/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
at nI (/Users/shubham/Desktop/website/real-estate-website/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)
at nM (/Users/shubham/Desktop/website/real-estate-website/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47570)
at nN (/Users/shubham/Desktop/website/real-estate-website/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
at nI (/Users/shubham/Desktop/website/real-estate-website/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)
at nM (/Users/shubham/Desktop/website/real-estate-website/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47570)
at nM (/Users/shubham/Desktop/website/real-estate-website/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61663)
 ✓ Generating static pages (11/11)`
```

I have tried making pages client components using the 'use client' directive on page.tsx files but it still fails.

Only one layout file is used.

```js
    import type { Metadata } from "next";
    import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
    import "./globals.css";

    const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

    export const metadata: Metadata = {
      title: "real estate ",
      description: "Property Management tool",
   };

    export default function RootLayout({
      children,
    }: Readonly<{
      children: React.ReactNode;
    }>) {
      return (
        <html lang="en">
          <body className='min-h-screen flex flex-col'>
            {children}
          </body>
        </html>
      );
    }
```

page.tsx

```js
    import ActualPage from './ActualPage'
    const Page = () => {
      return <>
        <ActualPage />
      </>
   }

   export default Page
```

ActualPage.tsx

```js
   "use client";
    import { PropertySubTypes } from "@/app/constants";
    import Select from "react-dropdown-select";    
    import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { usePathname, useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

export default function Home() {..}
```

**Edit**

One of components used in ActualPage code had a button with onClick updating window.location.href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the `window` object, along with other browser-specific objects like `document` or `navigator`, does not exist in Node.js, where Next.js server-side rendering (SSR) occurs.

For instance, if there's a module that uses window and is not under a useEffect (which runs only on the client side), you could modify it like so:

```js
// Before
const myVar = window.someFunction();

// After
let myVar;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    myVar = window.someFunction();
}
```

If you could check the content of the `ActualPage.tsx` I am sure there must be something related to above.

Please modify the question with the full content of `ActualPage.tsx` file, so we can resolve this.